# How to image upload in Amazon s3 webservice using android?

Tags: android

I need big help from you,I want to upload image using amazon s3 web service.I got bucket name,access key,secret key,I need help with How to implement code for upload images in amazon s3,i need sample code for that..

Thanks Friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the details here,

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4225549089557252

http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/toolkit/code-samples.html

And also check these,

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434

http://www.lysesoft.com/products/s3-bucketupload-android/

http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/

http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/faqs/